# Can't access my Web app running on a tomcat server from another computer in same network

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

here's my problem,  I have a Webservice that I run in tomcat using eclipse,  and I have an android app connected to that Webservice.  I access to that localhost using the local ip of my computer. Yes my phone is using same network. Sometimes when I launch the server, it's like I didnt, my app cant find a route and when I restart my computer everything works again. So my question is: What could be the problem because its kinda annoying to always have to restart my computer. I need a definitive solution. Thanks

Comment: probably dynamic IP issue. does that happen when you use a static one?

Comment: Yes it does happen